# How to do a Select in a Select

Tags: sql

I have a table containing a unique ID field. Another field (REF) contains a reference to another dataset's ID field.
Now I have to select all datasets where REF points to a dataset that doesn't exist.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ("no dataset with ID=REF exists")
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

3 ways

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable y WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT * FROM OtherTable o WHERE y.Ref = o.Ref)

SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE Ref NOT IN 
     (SELECT Ref FROM OtherTable WHERE Ref IS NOT NULL)

SELECT y.* FROM YourTable y 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  OtherTable o ON y.Ref = o.Ref
WHERE o.Ref IS NULL
```

See also [Five ways to return all rows from one table which are not in another table](http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/5_ways_to_return_rows_from_one_table_not_in_another_table)

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE NOT EXISTS 
     (SELECT * FROM OtherTable WHERE TABLE.Ref = OtherTable.ID)
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this should work

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT ref_id FROM ref_table)
```

or with JOIN

```
SELECT table.* 
FROM table LEFT JOIN ref_table ON table.id = ref_table.ref_id
WHERE ref_table.ref_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT 
 table1.* 
FROM 
 table1
 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.ref
WHERE 
 table2.ref IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do a subquery like:

```
select * from table where somefield not in (select otherfield from sometable where ID=REF)
```

Comment: you can't do somefield in (select *... as one field cannot evaluate to many

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE table2.id = table.ref) = 0)
```

Comment: hahaha! -2 points, I'm glad at least the code works even if it's not the neatest, otherwise who knows how many points less!

Answer (score 1):

Something like that :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID NOT IN(SELECT REF FROM Table2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use

select * from x where not exist ( select * from y )