# How does the IN predicate work in SQL?

Tags: sql, performance, optimization

After prepairing an answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761044/sql-query-help) I found I couldn't verify my answer.

In my first programming job I was told that a query within the `IN ()` predicate gets executed for every row contained in the parent query, and therefore using `IN` should be avoided.

For example, given the query:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Table1 WHERE Table1Id NOT IN (
SELECT Table1Id FROM Table2 WHERE id_user = 1)
```

```
Table1 Rows | # of "IN" executions
----------------------------------
      10    |       10
     100    |      100
    1000    |     1000
   10000    |    10000
```

Is this correct?  How does the `IN` predicate actually work?

Comment: Very good question. Don't see many questions asking for a breakdown of how certain things in SQL actually -work-. Often times people are more concerned with just getting the results they want.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The warning you got about subqueries executing for each row is true -- for **correlated subqueries.**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 a 
WHERE a.Table1id NOT IN (
  SELECT b.Table1Id FROM Table2 b WHERE b.id_user = a.id_user
);
```

Note that the subquery references the `id_user` column of the outer query.  The value of `id_user` on each row of `Table1` may be different.  So the subquery's result will likely be different, depending on the current row in the outer query.  The RDBMS *must* execute the subquery many times, once for each row in the outer query.

The example you tested is a **non-correlated subquery**.  Most modern RDBMS optimizers worth their salt should be able to tell when the subquery's result *doesn't* depend on the values in each row of the outer query.  In that case, the RDBMS runs the subquery a single time, caches its result, and uses it repeatedly for the predicate in the outer query.

PS:  In SQL, `IN()` is called a "predicate," not a statement.  A predicate is a part of the language that evaluates to either true or false, but cannot necessarily be executed independently as a statement.  That is, you can't just run this as an SQL query: "2 IN (1,2,3);"  Although this is a valid predicate, it's not a valid statement.

Comment: In MySQL, the subquery will be optimized to NOT EXISTS (which is DEPENDENT SUBQUERY), and will use index access on `INDEX ON Table2 (id_user, table1ID)` if it exists.

Answer (score 8):

It will entirely depend on the database you're using, and the exact query.

Query optimisers are very smart at times - in your sample query, I'd expect the better databases to be able to use the same sort of techniques that they do with a join. More naive databases may just execute the same query many times.

Comment: I agree, I just did a test query and I believe (I'm not great at reading ExecutionPlans) it created an inner join.

Answer (score 5):

This depends on the `RDBMS` in question.

See detailed analysis here:

- [**MySQL, part 1**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/18/counting-missing-rows/)
- [**MySQL, part 2**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/19/counting-missing-rows-using-distinc/)
- [**SQL Server**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/20/counting-missing-rows-sql-server/)
- [**Oracle**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/21/counting-missing-rows-oracle/)
- [**PostgreSQL**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/22/counting-missing-rows-postgresql/)

In short:

1. `MySQL` will optimize the query to this:

   ```
   SELECT  COUNT(*)
   FROM    Table1 t1
   WHERE   NOT EXISTS
           (
           SELECT  1
           FROM    Table2 t2
           WHERE   t2.id_user = 1
                   AND t2.Table1ID = t1.Table2ID
           )
   ```

   and run the inner subquery in a loop, using the index lookup each time.

   - `SQL Server` will use `MERGE ANTI JOIN`.

   The inner subquery will not be "executed" in a common sense of word, instead, the results from both query and subquery will be fetched concurrently.

   See the link above for detailed explanation.

   - `Oracle` will use `HASH ANTI JOIN`.

   The inner subquery will be executed once, and a hash table will be built from the resultset.

   The values from the outer query will be looked up in the hash table.

   - `PostgreSQL` will use `NOT (HASHED SUBPLAN)`.

   Much like `Oracle`.

Note that rewriting the query as this:

```
SELECT  (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    Table1
        ) - 
        (
        SELECT  COUNT(*)
        FROM    Table2 t2
        WHERE   (t2.id_user, t2.Table1ID) IN
                (
                SELECT  1, Table1ID
                FROM    Table1
                )
        )
```

will greatly improve the performance in all four systems.

Comment: Last time I looked, SQL Server only allows a single column to be returned from a subquery that is then used in an IN predicate. Has that changed?

Comment: @RolandTumble: no. `MySQL` and `PostgreSQL` allow that, `SQL Server` and `Oracle` don't. For the latter two systems, the `IN` predicate should be rewritten as `EXISTS`.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on optimizer. Check exact [query plan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_plan) for each particular query to see how the RDBMS will actually execute that.

In Oracle that'd be:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN FOR «your query»
```

In MySQL or PostgreSQL

```
EXPLAIN «your query»
```

Comment: @vartec - any resources on reading query plans?  This is a blind side of my knowledge and I've yet to find a decent article online.

Comment: it's DBMS dependent, but basically that gives you idea what basic operation it will do and in which order, which index will it use etc.

Comment: I think that what you'd have to look for, would be article about DB tuning, as this is a purpose of looking at query plans in the first place.

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79266/how-do-you-interpret-a-querys-explain-plan

Comment: I added a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761204/list-of-resources-for-database-tuning

Comment: good question actually, I've never though about how do I know about this stuff. Guess it came with experience ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Most SQL engines nowadays will almost always create the same execution plan for LEFT JOIN, NOT IN and NOT EXISTS

I would say look at your execution plan and find out  :-)

Also if you have NULL values for the Table1Id column you will not get any data back

Answer (score 0):

Not really. But it's butter to write such queries using JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but  execution stops as soon as the query processer "finds" the value you are looking for... So if, for example the first row in the outer select has Table1Id = 32, and if Table2 has a record with a TableId = 32, then 
   as soon as the subquery finds the row in Table2 where TableId = 32, it stops...