# IN vs. JOIN with large rowsets

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, performance, join

I'm wanting to select rows in a table where the primary key is in another table. I'm not sure if I should use a JOIN or the IN operator in SQL Server 2005. Is there any significant performance difference between these two SQL queries with a large dataset (i.e. millions of rows)?

```
SELECT *
FROM a
WHERE a.c IN (SELECT d FROM b)

SELECT a.*
FROM a JOIN b ON a.c = b.d
```

Comment: If you're going to use a join, use the modern syntax (e.g. SELECT ... FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.foo = b.foo

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761150/how-does-the-in-predicate-work-in-sql with an accepted answer that fits well with this question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Update:**

This article in my blog summarizes both my answer and my comments to another answers, and shows actual execution plans:

- [**IN vs. JOIN vs. EXISTS**](http://explainextended.com/2009/06/16/in-vs-join-vs-exists/)

---

```
SELECT  *
FROM    a
WHERE   a.c IN (SELECT d FROM b)

SELECT  a.*
FROM    a
JOIN    b
ON      a.c = b.d
```

These queries are not equivalent. They can yield different results if your table `b` is not key preserved (i. e. the values of `b.d` are not unique).

The equivalent of the first query is the following:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    a
JOIN    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT d
        FROM    b
        ) bo
ON      a.c = bo.d
```

If `b.d` is `UNIQUE` and marked as such (with a `UNIQUE INDEX` or `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`), then these queries are identical and most probably will use identical plans, since `SQL Server` is smart enough to take this into account.

`SQL Server` can employ one of the following methods to run this query:

- If there is an index on `a.c`, `d` is `UNIQUE` and `b` is relatively small compared to `a`, then the condition is propagated into the subquery and the plain `INNER JOIN` is used (with `b` leading)
- If there is an index on `b.d` and `d` is not `UNIQUE`, then the condition is also propagated and `LEFT SEMI JOIN` is used. It can also be used for the condition above.
- If there is an index on both `b.d` and `a.c` and they are large, then `MERGE SEMI JOIN` is used
- If there is no index on any table, then a hash table is built on `b` and `HASH SEMI JOIN` is used.

**Neither** of these methods reevaluates the whole subquery each time.

See this entry in my blog for more detail on how this works:

- [**Counting missing rows: SQL Server**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/20/counting-missing-rows-sql-server/)

There are links for all `RDBMS`'s of the big four.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation of what's going on behind the scenes.

Comment: I realize this is late, but does your article account for any query plan caching Voodoo? Given the fact that the related queries smell like your first, I'm curious if SQL Server is smart enough to use the cached query plan for the sake of saving time.

Answer (score 5):

Neither. Use an ANSI-92 JOIN:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a JOIN b a.c = b.d
```

However, it's best as an EXISTS

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM b WHERE a.c = b.d)
```

This remove the duplicates that could be generated by the JOIN, but runs just as fast if not faster

Comment: That sub-select is a correlated sub-select.  Whether the optimizer handles that efficiently is debatable - usually, they are bad for performance.

Comment: Assuming indexed columns, I've don't recall having a problem. Plan for plan, it works out similar on our boxes.

Answer (score 5):

Speaking from experience on a Table with 49,000,000 rows I would recommend LEFT OUTER JOIN.
Using IN, or EXISTS Took 5 minutes to complete where the LEFT OUTER JOIN finishes in 1 second.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.c = b.d
WHERE b.d is not null -- Given b.d is a primary Key with index
```

Actually in my query I do this across 9 tables.

Answer (score 4):

The IN is evaluated (and the select from b re-run) for each row in a, whereas the JOIN is optimized to use indices and other neat paging tricks...

In most cases, though, the optimizer would likely be able to construct a JOIN out of a correlated subquery and end up with the same execution plan anyway.

Edit: Kindly read the comments below for further... discussion about the validity of this answer, and the actual answer to the OP's question. =)

Comment: @JSTeen: No. The IN is a sequential "OR". @Rich: No ,EXISTS is a form of JOIN but gives more correct results

Comment: This answer is a big over-simplification. In a large number of cases, the optimizer will rephrase the IN as a JOIN, and it'll be just as fast as if you'd written the join yourself.

Comment: @skaffman is right, I have never seen a bogus plan like this for IN. It is always a join in my experience.

Comment: Trusting the optimizer is a fine thing, but you generally need to know a lot more about how and what the optimizer accomplishes with your query. Which is why I advocate using the method that's safer, in more cases. Yes? =)

Comment: However, I won't refuse to admit I'm wrong, if someone could point to some sort of article that explains the pitfalls? =)

Comment: SQL Server BOL? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx

In this case, EXISTS deals with NULL: Give me 5 to find more...

Comment: @J. Steen: http://explainextended.com/2009/04/20/counting-missing-rows-sql-server/ for SQL Server, and follow the links for other systems.

Comment: My MVP collegues has reminded me that IN can match a JOIN or EXISTS if the columns are *not* indexed. EXISTS and JOINS like indexes, usually, but IN is still lots of OR statements

Comment: @gbn, Right, EXISTS is superior to IN because of how it handles expected and returned results, fine. Does it outperform JOINs, though? I'm curious - if it does, I'll have to reevaluate. =)

Comment: @gbn: if there are not indexes, HASH JOIN / HASH SEMI JOIN will be chosen for JOIN / IN, appropriately. If the values of b.d are unique, both these methods will return exactly same results in exactly same time. If they're not, the JOIN and the IN queries will return different resultsets. IN resultset will of course be shorter and will be returned FASTER than the JOIN one.

Comment: @J. Steen: EXISTS will perform EXACTLY as fast as an IN query if there is an index, and MUCH slower if there is no index. It's EXISTS query that needs to be reevaluated for each for. For an IN query, a hash table will be built.

Comment: @Quassnoi, Oho! And that hashtable will then be used in subsequent hits of the subquery, I see!

Comment: @J. Steen: all methods that involve an IN clause are called SEMI JOIN's. There are NESTED LOOP SEMI JOIN, MERGE SEMI JOIN and HASH SEMI JOIN, neither of them reevaluates the whole subquery for each row. It's in fact query optimization 101 :)

Comment: @Quassnoi, remind me to spank my former DBA colleague, then. He quite obviously knew nothing of this and lured me into corruption!

Comment: @J. Steen: what you said initially is true for a non-indexed table in MySQL, since it's not capable of doing HASH JOIN's, but it's certainly not true for SQL Server. SQL Server could make HASH JOIN's since version 6.5 (it's when I started to use it), and probably even earlier.

Comment: @Quassnoi, well, that makes sense. The DBA started his career with MySQL to later convert to MSSQL.

Comment: @Quassnoi, re: IN vs EXISTS - iirc this is the opposite situation to SQL2000 (which I learned SQL on), can you point me at a source for this?

Comment: @annakata: EXISTS is more flexible than IN: any IN can be converted to an EXISTS, but not vice versa. For simple cases, when EXISTS can be converted into IN, in will be converted into some kind of a SEMI JOIN, and will perform as fast as an IN. For complex non-sargable and non-hashable cases, like EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM subtable WHERE FUNCTION(subtablecol1,outertable.col1) = 1), there is no other way but to evaluate the subquery for each pair of records).

Comment: @Quassnoi: My confusion stems from my expectation that Exists was always faster or equivalent to IN, not the other way around, but my SQL-foo is old and weak. Blog more on this please :)

Comment: @annakata: once a day, as usual :)

Answer (score 2):

Aside from going and actually testing it out on a big swath of test data for yourself, I would say use the JOINS. I've always had better performance using them in most cases compared to an IN subquery, and you have a lot more customization options as far as how to join, what is selected, what isn't, etc.

Comment: -1: It's true - You should prefer `JOIN`s wherever possible, but @Quassnoi's answer gets much closer to the metal and explains why and under what circumstances this is true. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1001592/109941

Answer (score 2):

They are different queries with different results. With the IN query you will get 1 row from table 'a' whenever the predicate matches. With the INNER JOIN query you will get a*b rows whenever the join condition matches.
So with values in a of {1,2,3} and b of {1,2,2,3} you will get 1,2,2,3 from the JOIN and 1,2,3 from the IN.

EDIT - I think you may come across a few answers in here that will give you a misconception. Go test it yourself and you will see these are all fine query plans:

```
create table t1 (t1id int primary key clustered)
create table t2 (t2id int identity primary key clustered
    ,t1id int references t1(t1id)
)


insert t1 values (1)
insert t1 values (2)
insert t1 values (3)
insert t1 values (4)
insert t1 values (5)

insert t2 values (1)
insert t2 values (2)
insert t2 values (2)
insert t2 values (3)
insert t2 values (4)


select * from t1 where t1id in (select t1id from t2)
select * from t1 where exists (select 1 from t2 where t2.t1id = t1.t1id)
select t1.* from t1 join t2 on t1.t1id = t2.t1id
```

The first two plans are identical. The last plan is a nested loop, this difference is expected because as I mentioned above the join has different semantics.

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575(SQL.90).aspx) on Subquery Fundamentals:

> Many Transact-SQL statements that
> include subqueries can be
> alternatively formulated as joins.
> Other questions can be posed only with
> subqueries. In Transact-SQL, there is
> usually no performance difference
> between a statement that includes a
> subquery and a semantically equivalent
> version that does not. However, in
> some cases where existence must be
> checked, a join yields better
> performance. Otherwise, the nested
> query must be processed for each
> result of the outer query to ensure
> elimination of duplicates. In such
> cases, a join approach would yield
> better results.

In the example you've provided, the nested query need only be processed a single time for each of the outer query results, so there should be no performance difference.  Checking the execution plans for both queries should confirm this.

Note: Though the question itself didn't specify SQL Server 2005, I answered with that assumption based on the question tags.  Other database engines (even different SQL Server versions) may not optimize in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Observe the execution plan for both types and draw your conclusions. Unless the number of records returned by the subquery in the "IN" statement is very small, the IN variant is almost certainly slower.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a join, betting that it'll be a heck of a lot faster than IN.  This presumes that there are primary keys defined, of course, thus letting indexing speed things up tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally held that a join would be more efficient than the IN subquery; however the SQL*Server optimizer normally results in no noticeable performance difference. Even so, it's probably best to code using the join condition to keep your standards consistent. Also, if your data and code ever needs to be migrated in the future, the database engine may not be so forgiving (for example using a join instead of an IN subquery makes a huge difference in MySql).

Answer (score 0):

Theory will only get you so far on questions like this.  At the end of the day, you'll want to test both queries and see which actually runs faster.  I've had cases where the JOIN version took over a minute and the IN version took less than a second.  I've also had cases where JOIN was actually faster.

Personally, I tend to start off with the IN version if I know I won't need any fields from the subquery table.  If that starts running slow, I'll optimize.  Fortunately, for large datasets,  rewriting the query makes such a noticeable difference that you can simply time it from Query Analyzer and know you're making progress.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Ive always been a supporter of the IN methodology. This link contains details of a test conducted in PostgresSQL.
http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-performance/2005-02/msg00327.php