# INSERT INTO statement that copies rows and auto-increments non-identity key ID column

Tags: sql, t-sql

Given a table that has three columns

1. ID (Primary Key, not-autoincrementing)
2. GroupID
3. SomeValue

I am trying to write a single SQL INSERT INTO statement that will make a copy of every row that has one GroupID into a new GroupID.

Example beginning table:

```
ID | GroupID | SomeValue
------------------------
1  |    1    |    a
2  |    1    |    b
```

Goal after I run a simple INSERT INTO statement:

```
ID | GroupID | SomeValue
------------------------
1  |    1    |    a
2  |    1    |    b
3  |    2    |    a
4  |    2    |    b
```

I thought I could do something like:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(       [ID]
       ,[GroupID]
       ,[SomeValue]
)
(
SELECT (SELECT MAX(ID) + 1 FROM MyTable)
       ,@NewGroupID
       ,[SomeValue]
 FROM MyTable
 WHERE ID = @OriginalGroupID
)
```

This causes a PrimaryKey violation since it will end up reusing the same Max(ID)+1 value multiple times as it seems.

Is my only recourse to a bunch of INSERT statements in a T-SQL WHILE statement that has an incrementing Counter value?

I also don't have the option of turning the ID into an auto-incrementing Identity column since that would breaking code I don't have source for.

Comment: it's better to move subquery(especially if it is one time computation) to JOIN, it's more performant.  if in any case other answers are slow, you can use mine

Comment: @Michael: `SQL Server` is smart enough to compute the expression like that only once.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Performance-wise, I always feel uneasy with subqueries in data projection. It's not rocket science moving the subquery in JOIN section anyhow.  Anway, I'll profile that in SQL Server later

Comment: @Quassnoi: I suggested your article on my comment here about correctness and speed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474964/using-tuples-in-sql-in-clause/1474974#1474974 . Your articles are very nice :-) Kudos

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `+ 1`, add the row number. I also fixed the error in your WHERE clause (should be `GroupID =`, not `ID =`):

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(       [ID]
       ,[GroupID]
       ,[SomeValue]
)
(
    SELECT
       (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM MyTable) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY GroupId),
       @NewGroupID,
       [SomeValue]
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE GroupID = @OriginalGroupID
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH    q AS
        (
        SELECT  *,
                (
                SELECT  MAX(id)
                FROM    mytable
                ) + ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS nid
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   groupID = 1
        )
INSERT
INTO    mytable (id, groupid, somevalue)
SELECT  nid, 2, somevalue
FROM    q
```

Comment: This also gives me the error: `The ranking function "ROW_NUMBER" must have an ORDER BY clause.`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(       [ID]
       ,[GroupID]
       ,[SomeValue]
)    
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() + X.MaxID 
       ,@NewGroupID
       ,[SomeValue]
 FROM MyTable
 CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) AS MaxID FROM MyTable) X 
 WHERE GroupID = @OriginalGroupID
```

Comment: In SQL Server 2008 I get a few errors when trying to run this command.

Comment: I found the first answer easiest to understand for my simple SQL knowledge.  However, it seems like I can get the same work done using a CROSS JOIN, I will try this out too.

Comment: I was able to get this to work also by adding the ORDER BY clause in the OVER() statement
e.g. SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY GroupID) + X.MaxID)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out what's missing. Interesting, OVER() without parameter in Postgres is working.  I will try in SQL Server later (I'm in OS X now) if parameter in OVER clause is optional.