# SQL INSERT: Increment an int value before insert

Tags: sql-server, insert

I have a variable,

```
DECLARE @CN int = (SELECT [CONTROL_NUMBER] FROM myTable)
```

I need to do an insert statement where the value of this variable is incremented during run time.

So,

```
INSERT INTO myTable2 (ControlNumber)
SELECT CNC+(@CN increment the value here) FROM aTable
```

So the values inserted will be like,

```
aa1234
ab1235
cd1236...
```

etc.

Definitely `@CN` is an int, so I will account for changing it to string before inserting the value.

Appreciate the help.

Thanks!

Comment: Ideally one should just leave the handling of the sequence values up to the database. Why this approach?

Comment: ^What he said.  Use an identity?

Comment: It is not an identity column.

Comment: I already have an identity column. The value needs to be inserted during run time based on the number of rows already inserted into the database.

Comment: Why aren't you using the identity column?

Comment: I have an identity column, this is some arbitrary value that I get from another table and need to increment it for every new row inserted.

Comment: I got it resolved through this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820668/insert-into-statement-that-copies-rows-and-auto-increments-non-identity-key-id-c

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @CN = @CN + 1
INSERT INTO myTable2 (ControlNumber) 
SELECT CNC + Cast(@CN as varchar) FROM aTable
```

Comment: Event though OP should probably being using an Identity column and a separate VARCHAR/CHAR column, this does technically answer his question.  +1 @OBL, please rethink your design here.