# Find a case which matchs with key-value pairs in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have encountered a sort of problem which I couldn't find true words to explain it, imagine I have some foreign keys that have some key-value pairs:

```
10 => (2, 3) , (4, 5)
11 => (2, 1), (4, 5)
```

It can be mapped in the following table:

```
 ID |  FK  |   Key  |  Value
-----------------------------
 1  |  10  |    2   |    3
 2  |  10  |    4   |    5
 3  |  11  |    2   |    1
 4  |  11  |    4   |    5
```

I want a query to find all FKs that their pairs are `(2, 3) AND (4, 5)` which the answer is `FK => 10` and that's where the problem appears!

If I use AND

```
  SELECT FK 
    FROM MyTable 
   WHERE (Key = 2 AND Value = 3) 
     AND
         (Key = 4 AND Value = 5)
```

It returns nothing and if I use OR:

```
SELECT FK 
  FROM MyTable 
 WHERE (Key = 2 AND Value = 3) 
    OR
       (Key = 4 AND Value = 5)
```

it returns 10 and 11 as answer which 11 is not the answer.

Actually I need more complicated query in my situation since I need to find a case that matches more than two key-value pairs.

Comment: You might want to have a look at answers in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006901/using-tuples-in-sql-in-clause

Comment: Check out this question and answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4047484/selecting-with-multiple-where-conditions-on-same-column

Answer (score 2):

You can try INTERSECT operator:

```
Select FK from <<tableName>> where key = 2 and value = 3
INTERSECT
Select FK from <<tableName>> where key = 4 and value = 5
```

Comment: It works, I had never heard of the key word `INTERSECT`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your current logic is on the right track, but anything in the `WHERE` clause will be applied to individual records.  On the other hand, you want to place these restrictions on *groups* of records belonging to the same `FK`.  If you want to find all `FK` having `(2, 3)` and `(4, 5)` as key value pairs, with each one occurring once, and no other pairs occurring, then use conditional aggregation with a `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT FK
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY FK
HAVING
    COUNT(*) = 2 AND    -- only two key/value pairs
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Key] = 2 AND Value = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1 AND   -- (2, 3)
    SUM(CASE WHEN [Key] = 4 AND Value = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 1;      -- (4, 5)
```

Note: You should probably avoid calling your columns (or tables, etc.) `Key`, because that might be a reserved keyword in SQL Server, and most flavors of SQL.  Use something else.

Comment: Thanks, it works correctly, but I wish I didn't use `CASE WHEN` since it's expensive and the number of rows is going to be so much. Anyway, thanks.