# SQL Server: How do I return all columns where one is not repeated?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct, group-concat

I've got a table with repeating IDs which I will fix later. Basically I want to return all the rows where the ID is distinct, but I want the ENTIRE row. Something like:

```
select * from table group by ID

select * from table where (ID is not repeated)
```

In this case, they are identical rows, so I don't care if it's First or Last, Min or Max.

Note that I DON"T want to do this:

```
select MIN(col1), MIN(col2), ... from table group by ID
```

I want a way to get this result without enumerating every column.

Edit: I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MySql, do this:

```
select 
    *
from tbl
group by ID
```

MySQL live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c7fd/2

If you are using Postgresql, do this:

```
select distinct on(id)
    *
from tbl
order by id
```

If you want Postgresql DISTINCT ON be at least as predictable as CTE windowing function. Sort another column:

```
select distinct on(id)
    *
from tbl
order by id
   , someColumnHere -- Choose ASC for first row, DESC for last row
```

Postgresql live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/8c7fd/1

If you are using CTE windowing-capable database (e.g. Postgres, Oracle, Sql Server), use this:

```
with ranked as
(
  select 
      rank() over(partition by id order by column) rn,
      *
  from tbl
)
select * from ranked where rn = 1
```

CTE windowing-capable databases:

Posgtresql: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/8c7fd/2

Oracle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b5cf9/1

Sql Server: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8c7fd/3

Comment: Unless Id is the only column, this won't work without supplying an aggregate function for each column

Comment: Who said so that aggregate function is a necessity on MySql if you want to do a GROUP BY? See the result here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c7fd/1

Comment: Op didn't specify MySql, and it is a necessity in other databases. I appreciate the lesson, but I was just trying to help.

Comment: It's ok dude ;-) Really, MySQL violates many database fundamentals, that's why you presumed my first query is incorrect, yeah it is incorrect on virtually all database platform; however, it's correct in MySQL. See an example of what a good GROUP BY should be like and strive of doing so: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/08/postgresql-recognizing-functional.html

Comment: I'm using SQL Server, so this isn't an option. It's good to know that I can do this in MySQL though, thanks.

Comment: you can also use row_number, it's similar with rank; I have yet to see where they do differs(though I think it has). rank is more semantic than row_number. it's like the difference between `<em>` and `<i>` tag :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't state in your question what database are you using, I suggest you make a query that will work on all database platforms. But this query requires you to make a new column with a property of auto_number,identity,serial,etc

This would be the query:

```
select * from tbl 
where (id,auto_number_here) in
   (select id, min(auto_number_here) 
    from tbl 
    group by id)
```

That will work on *many* platforms, except Sql Server. Sql Server is not tuple-capable. You have to do this:

```
select * from tbl x
where 
   -- leave this comment, so it mimics the tuple capability
   -- (id,auto_number_here) in
   EXISTS
   (select
       -- Replace this:  
       -- id, min(auto_number_here) 

       -- With whatever floats your boat, 
       -- you can use 1, null(the value generated by Entity Framework's EXIST clause), 
       -- even 1/0 is ok :-) (this will not result to divide-by-zero error)

       -- But I prefer retaining the columns, so it mimics the tuple-capable database:
       id, min(auto_number_here) 

    from tbl 
    where id = x.id 
    group by id
    having x.auto_number_here = min(auto_number_here))
```

Tuple-related question: [using tuples in sql in clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474964/using-tuples-in-sql-in-clause)

Since some [database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) doesn't support tuple, you can [simulate it](http://www.anicehumble.com/2012/05/tuple-matching-is-neat-how-to-simulate.html) instead

```
select z.* from tbl z
join (select id, min(auto_number_here) as first_row from tbl group by id) as x
on z.id = x.id and z.auto_number_here = x.first_row
```

It's a bit better than EXISTS approach. But if your database supports tuple use it instead; as much as possible, use JOIN for reflecting table relationships only, and use WHERE clause for filtering.

---

**UPDATE**

Perhaps a concrete example could explain it clearly, suppose we have existing table that we forgot to put a primary key on:

```
create table tbl(
  id varchar(5), -- supposedly primary key 
  data int,
  message varchar(100) 
);


insert into tbl values
('A',1,'the'),
('A',1,'quick'),
('A',4,'brown'),
('B',2, 'fox'),
('B',5, 'jumps'),
('B',5, 'over'),
('C',6, 'the'),
('C',7, 'lazy');
```

In order to pick up only one row out of duplicates, we need to add a third column on existing data.

This will aid us on picking up one and only one row out of duplicates

```
alter table tbl add auto_number_here int identity(1,1) not null;
```

This shall work now:

```
select z.* from tbl z
join (select id, min(auto_number_here) as first_row from tbl group by id) as x
on z.id = x.id and z.auto_number_here = x.first_row
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19b55/3

And so is this:

```
select * from tbl x
where 
   -- leave this comment, so it mimics the tuple capability
   -- (id,auto_number_here) in
   EXISTS
   (
     select
       -- Replace this:  
       -- id, min(auto_number_here) 

       -- With whatever floats your boat, 
       -- you can use 1, null(the value generated by Entity Framework's EXIST clause), 
       -- even 1/0 is ok :-) (this will not result to divide-by-zero error)

       -- But I prefer retaining the columns, so it mimics the tuple-capable database:
       id, min(auto_number_here) 

    from tbl 
    where id = x.id 
    group by id
    having x.auto_number_here = min(auto_number_here)

   )
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/19b55/4

Comment: What is auto_number_here? I'm not sure I'm understanding that part.

Comment: auto_numbered column. it's like Sql Server's identity

Comment: 942 rows, just like what I'm getting with a select *. There's only 880 unique IDs.

Comment: Have you created a unique number for the entire rows. Each row should have their own unique number. You can use identity(1,1) for that column. Then the above query will work. Use a column that has no repeating values (ideally from identity(sql server),auto_number(mysql),serial(postgresql)) for the `auto_number_here` on your `MIN(auto_number_here)` expression

Comment: Don't use a column with duplicate values on that `MIN` aggregate

Comment: I gave a new example on my answer now. Check its sqlfiddle too

Comment: If your query involves multiple one-to-many tables, perhaps you should flatten out your query results first before your query pick up one row out of it. See example of query results flattening http://www.anicehumble.com/2012/05/sql-count-computer-program-does-what.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. It might work because all columns in the two rows are identical.

```
select distinct *
from table
```

Comment: That worked somewhat. 880 results in the table, 942 in the view. I only want the 880 (the view is doing some joins that are adding unwanted rows, and I don't have time to rewrite them right now). That command returned 899, adding 19 results - so apparently they aren't exactly identical - though the ID columns are.

Comment: In that case, you'll have to choose between the two rows, writing out Min(Col1), ... After all, SQL doesn't know how to decide which of two slightly different rows to return.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to get your unique ids, then use that to filter the results:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable t,
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Id, COUNT(*) 'count'
  FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY Id
) sq ON sq.Id = t.Id
WHERE sq.count = 1
```

Comment: The second subquery is a bit overkill. You could just do `SELECT sqq.Id, COUNT(1) 'count' FROM YourTable sqq GROUP BY sqq.Id`

Comment: @diaho good point, not sure what I was thinking there. Thanks!

Comment: Both of these return 831 rows, where there are 880 unique rows. Essentially I do want the ones with count > 1, but only the first one.

Comment: Suggesting `COUNT(1)` for `COUNT(*)` is a [Cargo Cult Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) . See this: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/04/debunking-myth-that-countdracula-is.html And this: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/05/why-is-exists-select-1-cargo-cult.html

Comment: what's overkill here is he can move the count filter from WHERE clause  to inside of subquery and put it in HAVING. `INNER JOIN(SELECT id FROM YourTable GROUP BY Id HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) sq ON sq.Id = t.Id`.  But just the same, this is not what the OP asked, he don't want rows with no duplicates only

Comment: reason for downvote? Also @Michael Buen please stick to the question asked instead of shoving a ton of unnecessary content down everyone's throats. It's not productive but it's certainly very annoying. We get it, you are the world's foremost expert on databases.