# A proposed solution for aggregate function for "LAST" in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a log table which looks as follows:

```
logs (_id_, client, metric, value);
```

I am attempting to write the following query in MySQL from a PHP front end to get information out of a log table.

```
SELECT client, LAST(value) AS value
FROM logs 
WHERE metric = 'free space'
GROUP BY client;
```

Except, of course, that `LAST` is not a valid aggregate function.

My proposed solution is this:

```
SELECT client, value 
FROM logs 
WHERE id IN (
   SELECT MAX(id) 
   FROM logs 
   WHERE metric = 'free space' 
   GROUP BY client);
```

However, for a very small table of 4,000 rows, this query takes in excess of 60 seconds to execute on my development machine.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do this with a join

```
SELECT l.client, l.value 
  FROM logs l
  JOIN ( SELECT client, MAX(id) as id
           FROM logs 
          WHERE metric = 'free space' 
          GROUP BY client ) s
    ON l.id = s.id
```

You should also have a (unique if possible) index on `id` for the outer query, this enables the join to use the indexes. If optimisation is massively important you may also want an index on `client, id`, or possibly `id, client`, for the sub-select, though this isn't as important as you have to scan the entire table anyway.

Please also see [SQL JOIN vs IN performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200295/sql-join-vs-in-performance) and [IN vs. JOIN with large rowsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001543/in-vs-join-with-large-rowsets) for discussions around using `in` or `join`.

Comment: Thanks @Ben - the id field is indexed (primary key) so this will work perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This query provides the latest row after performing the group by operation.
Joining of another table is also shown.

SELECT messages.* , `users`.`id` AS user_id,
`users`.`first_name`,
`users`.`last_name`
FROM messages
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `messages`.`sender_id`
WHERE messages.id IN (
SELECT MAX(messages.id) 
FROM messages 
WHERE messages.receiver_id = 2 
GROUP BY messages.sender_id);