# sqlserver self join - optimal way?

Tags: sql-server, self-join

I have written the below query. I do not think it is the optimum way.
The scenario is - given a child, I want to fetch all rows corresponding to its parent(root).

```
select * from TableA where column_root = 
(select column_root from TableA where column_child = 123)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JOIN`:

```
select T1.* from 
    TableA T1 join
    TableA T2 ON T1.column_root=T2.column_root
where T2.column_child = 123
```

Sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9316/1)

Comment: In my scenario, if a child has more than 1 root, that would mean there is some data issue.

Comment: @AdarshK: So you are saying, there will be only one record with column_child=123? Or there will be only one column_root for child 123?

Comment: Both. only unique child records, for a given child record only one root.

Comment: @AdarshK: Then why not `select * from TableA where column_child = 123`??

Comment: That gives only one record, where as i need all children under the record 123's parent_root.

Comment: @AdarshK: Updated my answer. Try it! Also see the fiddle demo.

Comment: @AdarshK: See [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001543/in-vs-join-with-large-rowsets).