# SQL Alchemy return list of ids

Tags: sqlalchemy, pylons

I am using SQL Alchemy and I want to return a list of Document Ids. The Ids are the primary key in the documents table. My current query returns a list of tuples.

```
userDocs = session.query(Document.idDocument).filter(Document.User_idUser == user.idUser).all()
```

The reason I want a list of ids is so that I can search another table using in_(userDocs).

So another solution would be to be able to search using tuples. I am currently returning nothing from my second query using userDocs.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do an intermediate query, you can do this all in one shot!

```
things = session.query(Things) \
                .join(Thing.documents) \
                .filter(Document.User_idUser==user.idUser)
```

You just query on the properties of the Document through its `relationship()` on the intended entity.

Comment: I agree with @TokenMacGuy: you should just extend your (second) query by adding a `join` to the `Document` table and adding that `filter` to it. In this way you will get your results in one query (one `SQL` statement). Even if you do not have a `relationship` between `Thing` and `Document`, you can still `join` with explicit condition. Not to mention that the `IN` operator might be sub-optimal in general (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013797/is-sql-in-bad-for-performance)

Comment: Thank you. Perfect, wasn't thinking of using its relationships to filter. I was trying some experimentation with nested queries that didn't turn out well, but this seems to be the best way. Thanks!

Comment: i think you mean query(Things).join(Thing.documents).filter(Document.User_idUser==user.idUser), you can't navigate into the next entity directly from Thing.documents (SQLA won't implicitly join)