# How to make SQLite select query faster

Tags: android, sqlite

Hello I am pretty new with `SQLite` and I am trying to deal with some database manipulation in my project.

I have a table with almost **4000** rows and this is the format of every row:

```
problem_id (string)
problem_no (string)
problem_title (string)
dacu (int)
```

I need to query a bunch of `problem_no` based on the `problem_id`. The quantity of query is almost 1000 at a time. So I wrote a query code like this:

```
Set<Integer> getProblemsTitle(HashSet<String> problemsIDs) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        HashSet<Integer> problemNo = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        for (Iterator<String> iterator = problemsIDs.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            cursor = db.query(CommonUtils.PROBLEM_TABLE, new String[] {
                    CommonUtils.KEY_PROBLEM_NO },
                    CommonUtils.KEY_PROBLEM_ID + "=?",
                    new String[] { iterator.next() }, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                problemNo.add(cursor.getInt(0));
            }
            cursor.close();
        }
        db.close();
        Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>(problemNo);
        return set;
    }
```

I know this is not a optimized snippet. And I need to optimize it a lot to reduce the execution time of the query. I did it inside `AsyncTask` but it is taking too much time.

How can I do this efficiently with faster performance?

Comment: This isn't how I would look up titles for an associated record. I would use a `LEFT JOIN` so that when you query problems you also get the problem titles. I'd think you need to clarify where `problemsIDs` comes from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to consider taking this out of the database. If you just grabbed all the problems, you could add them all in code. Running one `SELECT` with 4000 results is still going to be *much* faster than a thousand `SELECT` statements.

The approach would be to grab them all, but sorted(`ORDER BY problem_id`). You could then just check each item in `problemIDs` against it, and add when you get a match.

You could also use the `IN` operator as [Mathew suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18081920/752320), but [I don't know how efficient that will be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1013959/752320) with 1000 items in the set.

Comment: I missed the part about a 1000 ids.

Comment: @Geobits and @Mathew Foscarini, I need to do a lot of single item query like this. So should I query all the database and map in `hasMap`? It will 4000 map insertion operation and each map insertion operation will take `O(1)`. Would it be efficient?

Comment: You can't control where the user stores your app. If they put it on an SD card then read/write speeds will kill performance. If the data is mostly static, then either preload it all or cache it in a map. You will do two things 1) save performance 2) save battery. Loading data from storage on Android isn't good for battery life.

Answer (score 1):

Don't iterate over a collection of IDs, but use the `IN` operator in a `WHERE` condition.

`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE problem_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)`

This will return all the records in the set. Whereas you are querying them one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This seems to be faster. `This will return all the records in the set. Whereas you are querying them one at a time.` Can you give me some working example with full code? I am new in SQLite

Comment: I don't do much SQLite. Sorry, maybe this will help. http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You could try [compiling a query](http://simonwdixon.wordpress.com/2011/08/16/android-sqllite-tip-2-use-compiled-sql-statements/), and maybe you can try to load the database into memory before reading.

Answer (score -1):

Create an index on the `problem_id` column.