# Get Rest of Data in Many to Many Relationship

Tags: sql, algorithm

I have customer and group tables, in many to many relationship. For example I have *gold* group. This group consist of some customer instance. I need list of customer that NOT IN *gold* member. Simple solution I use this query

```
Select * from customer where id not in (select customer_id from customer_group where group_id = 1)
```

This solution to be worst, when my database grow up, thousands customer instance. I need suggestion of an effective approach for this condition.

Comment: how many rows are in the customers table?

Comment: In worst case scenario. I have 10,000 customer. And 9,999 of them is gold member. How I get 1 customer that not gold member?

Answer (score 0):

The `where in` clause can be very inefficient and heavy on your database and hence should be avoided. (see [Is SQL IN bad for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013797/is-sql-in-bad-for-performance))

Instead you should use `join` for better performance:

```
SELECT * FROM customer 
LEFT JOIN customer_group
ON customer.customer_id = customer_group.customer_id 
WHERE customer_group.group_id <> 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use joins instead of subqueries:

```
 Select * 
 from 
        customer cc
        inner join customer_group grp on grp.customer_id=cc.customer_id
 where 
     grp.group_id <>1
```

Execution plans - Subqueries costs are bigger.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use not exists query instead of where in.

```
 Select * from customer c 
  where 
 not exists(select customer_id from customer_group g 
      where group_id = 1 and c.id = g.customer_id);
```

In this we are first finding out the customer in `customer_group` with same `customer_id` as c's id and also is a `gold` member. And if there is no row returned (it means it does not exists) we return all his information from `customer` table.