# How to pass values in dictionary to sql query in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a dictionary, where I have stored 1000s of Ids and in a set i have few dates.

```
deliveryDict={} //-->Contains 1000s of IDs, need to be passed in sql to query the DB
timestamp_set = set([]) //-->contains dates
```

My sql query is like;

```
    sqlstatement = 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ObservationData]  as obs
     where obs.TankSystemId in< IDs from dictionary> and obs.TimeStamp in <date from set>'

 cursor.execute(sqlstatement)
```

How can I pass this to my sql query?
I expect my query would be like;

```
 sqlstatement = 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ObservationData]  as obs
         where obs.TankSystemId in (1,2,3,4,5...) and obs.TimeStamp in ('2019-01-01','2019-01-02') '
```

so my output would be;
table of records

Comment: It would be good if you could include sample input and expected output.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM i editedmy quetsion with sample

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python list in sql query as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283645/python-list-in-sql-query-as-parameter)

Comment: @Ratha do you really want to pass all the 1000s of ids into a WHERE clause for a single query? Or do you want to pass one ID per query?

Comment: @gregory all ids at once, because i need to update 1000s of records in DB. SO wanted to query DB first with all Ids and do update once rater update one by one.

Comment: @Ratha, ah..that seems awfully expensive and perhaps infeasible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013797/is-sql-in-bad-for-performance

Answer (score 0):

Include variables as follows:

```
sqlstatement = 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[ObservationData]  as obs
         where obs.TankSystemId in '+ str(deliveryDict) +' and obs.TimeStamp in '+ str(timestamp_set)
```

If you want to pass values individually, query from within a for loop.