# If there is more than a thousand whereNotIn in Laravel DB, will it lead to a decrease in speed?

Tags: laravel

I am doing a test solution module at Laravel. Users solve the test. And properly solved tests will not be returned to users.

Questions are always mixed. Obtained by random method.

My code:

`$test_status= DB::table('test_status')->where('status', '=', 'check')-select('id')->get();`

`$test= DB::table('test')->whereNotIn('id', $test_status)->inRandomOrder()->first();`

In this case, I will not show the user back the tests that he has previously solved.

The problem is that if the user has found the answer to 10,000 tests, will it be too late for me to get a query from the database? If there is a better way, please share

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is SQL IN bad for performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013797/is-sql-in-bad-for-performance)

Comment: if your first query is slow, then make an index `status` column

Comment: This does not fit my question

Comment: Droid, Can you tell me exactly how?

Comment: I am just curious, `whereNotIn()` accept an index array, but in your case `$test_status` is a arry + object

Comment: I'd say that that question is your exact case. 
If you have a few records, using any `WHERE IN / WHERE NOT in` is not a problem.
10000 is just too much for that, even if you have an index on `status`.

Look at `UNION / EXCEPT / INTERSECT`.

Comment: You might run into the problem that the query itself is too long or exceeds the amount of bound parameters allowed rather than performance issues.