# Limitation on IN()

Tags: sql, oracle11g

What is the limitation of number of values that are passed inside IN() in SQL query? I have been looking around about this online but not found the answer I was looking for?

Comment: How hard did you look?  It took me less than a minute with a google search string of "oracle list item limit".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When explicitly stated the limit is 1,000, i.e.:

```
select * from the_table where id in (1, 2, ..., 1000)
```

This is in the [documentation on the IN conditon](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions013.htm#i1050801):

> You can specify up to 1000 expressions in expression_list.

When not explicitly stated there is no limit:

```
select * from table1 where id in ( select id from table2 )
```

Though useful there are often better ways of passing this many or more values to a SELECT. It might be worth considering a reference table of some description or JOIN.

See also:

- [IN vs. JOIN with large rowsets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001543/in-vs-join-with-large-rowsets)
- [How does the IN predicate work in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761150/how-does-the-in-predicate-work-in-sql)

Comment: So what would be best alternative if IN() is not sufficient? suppose if we have big query where one column ColumnA will have to consider many values (>1000) while during run time (I am talking about dynamically considering values). I dont know if I putting it correct, Example,