# ORACLE SQL,PL/SQL limitations

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In Oracle we have the limitation of only 1000 items supported in the IN clause of SQL. I would like to know if there are any other such limitations in Oracle.

Comment: 1000 items in an IN is a lot.... you may want to reconsider your SQL if you are approaching this limit.

Comment: It might be a lot, but I have to contend with it quite a lot.  It depends on the nature of the task at hand.

Comment: A simple alternative is to use a bulk insert into a temporary table and use an `IN` on a subquery on -- or just a join to -- said temporary table (in case anyone is interested in ways around the in-1000-item-limitation).

Comment: Too broad - unless you're satisfied that the answer to "is there are any other such limitations in Oracle" is, "yes".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limitation on IN()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19304570/limitation-on-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various limits are documented here for 11.2: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/limits003.htm

Some edition-based limitations: http://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/enterprise-edition/comparisons/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Limits for Oracle 10g:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits.htm

Logical limits:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits003.htm

Physical limits:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits002.htm

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple trick to bypass this limit.
I use it sometimes in ad hoc queries.
Tested on Oracle 11.2g for 5000 items.
Drawback of this method is long parse time (about 5-10 seconds on my system for 5000 items).

```
WITH list AS (
select 1 as X from dual union all
select 2 from dual union all
select 3 from dual union all
......
......
......
select 4997 from dual union all
select 4998 from dual union all
select 4999 from dual union all
select 5000 from dual 
)
SELECT /*+gather_plan_statistics */ * FROM table123
WHERE x IN ( SELECT * FROM list );



select * from table( dbms_xplan.display_cursor (format=>'ALLSTATS LAST'));
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                       
| Id  | Operation            | Name     | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers |  OMem |  1Mem | Used-Mem |                                                                                                                                                                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |          |      1 |        |   5000 |00:00:00.24 |      29 |       |       |          |                                                                                                                                                                                       
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN RIGHT SEMI|          |      1 |      1 |   5000 |00:00:00.24 |      29 |  1066K|  1066K| 1339K (0)|                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   2 |   VIEW               | VW_NSO_1 |      1 |   5000 |   5000 |00:00:00.24 |       0 |       |       |          |                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   3 |    VIEW              |          |      1 |   5000 |   5000 |00:00:00.21 |       0 |       |       |          |                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   4 |     UNION-ALL        |          |      1 |        |   5000 |00:00:00.18 |       0 |       |       |          |                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   5 |      FAST DUAL       |          |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   6 |      FAST DUAL       |          |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   7 |      FAST DUAL       |          |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   8 |      FAST DUAL       |          |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |                                                                                                                                                                                       
|   9 |      FAST DUAL       |          |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          | 
..........
..........
..........
|5000 |      FAST DUAL       |          |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |                                                                                                                                                                                       
|5001 |      FAST DUAL       |          |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |                                                                                                                                                                                       
|5002 |      FAST DUAL       |          |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |                                                                                                                                                                                       
|5003 |      FAST DUAL       |          |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |                                                                                                                                                                                       
|5004 |      FAST DUAL       |          |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       0 |       |       |          |                                                                                                                                                                                       
|5005 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | TABLE123 |      1 |   9999 |   9999 |00:00:00.02 |      29 |       |       |          |                                                                                                                                                                                       
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: That's a good trick.  You can significantly improve performance by combining many of the `SELECT`s together like this: `select column_value x from table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,...  )) union all ...`.  Although building a string like that is more difficult.