# SQL Server CE retrieve a field from the record with the MAX(Id)

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

I am using SQL Server Compact 4.0 and am trying to get one query to return a single record with a column `Alarm` based on the maximum identity when another column `Cleared` is `NULL`.

This works:

```
SELECT Id, Alarm 
FROM Alarm_History 
WHERE Cleared IS NULL
```

Giving me half the answer. The problem is that it returns several records.

This also works:

```
SELECT MAX(Id) 
FROM Alarm_History 
WHERE Cleared IS NULL
```

And it gives me the other half of the answer, but I can't get the value "Alarm" that I am looking for.

But they DON'T work together as in:

```
SELECT Id, Alarm 
FROM Alarm_History 
WHERE Cleared IS NULL AND Id = MAX(Id)
```

OR

```
SELECT MAX(Id), Alarm 
FROM Alarm_History 
WHERE Cleared IS NULL
```

With the queries above I can do two consecutive queries to get the result back, but I don't think this is very efficient. Is there a way to do this in one trip to the database?

Thanks
Jeff

Comment: "With the queries above I can do two consecutive queries to get the result back, but I don't think this is very efficient. " yet you accept the answer with two queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with max and a join, but that would be far too complicated. Instead, you can just try:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id, Alarm
FROM Alarm_History
WHERE Cleared IS NULL
ORDER BY Id DESC
```

**Note:** what happens if two alarms have max id ? Well, that shouldn't happen (Id is unique). But that's an interesting problem nevertheless (suppose the field is not Id but Price, and you want all alarms with max price, and you don't know how many there'll be, so you cannot use TOP 1 anymore).
You'll have to use a CROSS JOIN;

```
SELECT Id, Price
FROM Alarms
JOIN (SELECT MAX(Price) as maxPrice FROM Alarms) b
WHERE Alarms.Price = b.maxPrice
```

Comment: Sorry, used MySql syntax. Edited.

Comment: Does the answer I previously accepted take two trips to the database to get the result I am looking for? If so what you are saying makes perfect sense to me and I think I am beginning to understand. In my original question I was concerned with writing two queries and then having to manage the results separately. That seemed like a lot of unnecessary code and I like your answer more.

Comment: @JeffPatterson see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761150/how-does-the-in-predicate-work-in-sql?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Don't think "max".  Think "order by".  Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Id, Alarm
FROM Alarm_History
WHERE Cleared IS NULL
ORDER BY Id DESC;
```

That way, you can get all the fields you want associated with the max id.

Comment: This works as well as the answer not using "TOP" and not having to sort. I can't tell which is actually more efficient and I appreciate the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
SELECT Id, Alarm FROM Alarm_History WHERE ID in (SELECT MAX(Id) FROM Alarm_History WHERE Cleared IS NULL)
```